# Stop Django printing GET and POST statements to the console?

Tags: django, debugging

When I run Django locally using `runserver`:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

and then load up a page, I see tons of GET requests printed at the console.

```
[15/Jul/2013 12:40:12] "GET /media/img/thumbnails/AW-44355258.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[15/Jul/2013 12:40:12] "GET /media/img/thumbnails/AW-44359161.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[15/Jul/2013 12:40:12] "GET /media/img/thumbnails/AW-44388528.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

How can I stop Django printing these? They're distracting me from other debug statements.

I want to keep `DEBUG` set to `TRUE` so that I can do other debugging at the console.

Comment: There are duplicate *answers* but I'm not so sure this is really a duplicate *question*. At least, I searched SO quite a bit before posting and I didn't find the "duplicate" - so  others are likely to post the same question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the development server. What you can do is run your development code in a different server on your local machine with the django debug options turned on.